# Sharing one background service between another background services and application services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I want to use BackgroundService for sending notification emails in my web api project (.net 5). Message sending is initiated from several API endpoints and also from another BackgroundService, which makes some periodical operations on database and then sends notifications if needed. As I understood from documentation and various examples over the internet, I have to create a queue class (with ConcurrentQueue inside), register it as Singleton in DI container and inject it into both workers (producer & consumer) and also into application services (or maybe controllers). Queueing a email will look like this:

```cs
// ... application service code
var notification = new SomeEventNotification("email goes here");
notificationQueue.Enqueue(notification);
```

Am I going the right way?

Comment: Sounds like a common approach. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: You're on the right track but I suggest you check out `System.Threading.Channels` https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/